# Keyerror while importing CEC modules

Tags: python, pvlib

I can import the module from `Sandia` Module database using the script

```
sandia_modules = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('SandiaMod')
module = sandia_modules['Canadian_Solar_CS6X_300M__2013_']
```

But I have a problem importing the module from `CEC` module database

```
cec_modules = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('CECMod')
module = cec_modules['Canadian_Solar_Inc__CS6K_300MS']
```

While executing, gives
KeyError: 'Canadian_Solar_Inc__CS6K_300MS'

I took the module from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NREL/SAM/develop/deploy/libraries/CEC%20Modules.csv

I would like to know the naming convention for CEC modules.

Comment: @RoshinRaphel This edit did not improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Missing module

I can retrieve that module with latest `pvlib`. Could you be using an outdated version of `pvlib`?

With `0.7.2` I can confirm `"Canadian_Solar_Inc__CS6K_300MS"` is in the `cecmod` database.

Note that `pvlib`, as of today, has [its own copy of SAM's CSV files](https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/blob/master/pvlib/data/sam-library-cec-modules-2019-03-05.csv), so sometimes the copy is outdated with respect to SAM's.

### Naming conventions

The naming is not decided by `pvlib`. Although `pvlib` [chose to replace all spaces and "special" characters with `_`](https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/issues/768) (hence the difference with respect to SAM's names), it just takes the original names in SAM's CSV files.

So, is SAM responsible for these names then? [It seems not](https://github.com/NREL/SAM/issues/227#issuecomment-541347853). They just process the names from the CEC database exactly as they record them.

So at the end it is the CEC, which collects module and inverter efficiency measurements for listing products to qualify for California's credits, the one responsible for the naming.

Unfortunately, a convention does not seem to exist yet, so CEC module names may change in the future.